# Trouble with xsl:for-each

Tags: xslt

I must be missing some fundamental concept of processing an XML document.  Here is my source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Root>
  <Element>visitorNameAlt</Element>
  <Element>visitorScore</Element>
  <Element>visitorTimeouts</Element>
  <Element>Blank</Element>
  <Element>homeNameAlt</Element>
  <Element>homeScore</Element>
  <Element>homeTimeouts</Element>
  <Element>Blank</Element>
  <Element>period</Element>
  <Element>optionalText</Element>
  <Element>flag</Element>
  <Element>Blank</Element>
  <Element>scoreLogo</Element>
  <Element>sponsorLogo</Element>
</Root>
```

And my XSL stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/Root">
        <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="Element"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

All I want is to pluck the "Element" names from the source XML doc with their relative position in front.

My output is just "1" followed by the first element and nothing more.

I am new to XSLT, but have processed other documents successfully with for-each.

Thanks in advance.

Bill

Comment: "for each Root" means exactly what it says - process each Root once. There's only one Root, so I can't see how you imagine the body of the for-each will be executed more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping over Root tags, not Element tags. Try this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="/Root/Element">
     <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that you must change the second value-of select to "." or "text()".

Comment: Think of your XML documents as of trees. Now the _for-each_ will try to match the path given to _select_ declarative-style against the tree structure.

Comment: Thank you.  That worked for me.  Unfortunately, the XML file is the result of the first pass of a two-pass attempt at processing a more complicated XML file.  The solution worked on the interim result saved as a standalone XML file, but not for the whole schmeer.  I'll need to evaluate what's wrong now and possibly submit another question.  But thank you for helping me clear this hurdle.

Comment: P.S.: I am using the node-set extension on the tree fragment resulting from the first pass, so I don't think that's the problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

XSLT is not an imperative programming language.  The XSLT processor grabs each element in turn and tries to match it to your stylesheet.  The idiomatic way to write this is *without* a for-each:

```
<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Element"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Element">
    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

The first template matches the root and tells the processor to apply the stylesheet to all the `Element` nodes inside the `Root`.  The second template matches those nodes, and outputs the desired information.